# Will my Indian e-Visa be ok for my 2 weeks travel?

Tags: visas, india, italian-citizens

I have been granted a 30 days Indian eVisa for a 2 weeks travel. In the mail for the visa it states:

> Date of issue of ETA :- February 06th,2020
>
> Date of expiry of ETA :- March 06th,2020
>
> e-Tourist Visa Validity period is 30 days from the date of first arrival in India.

I will land in India the 3rd of March, and will depart the 14th of March. Will I face any problem?

As I understand, I have 30days from the day I enter India to leave, so I should be covered, but the date of expiry is worrying me. Anyone can share their experience?

Comment: Currently (in Feb 2020), e-Visa's are temporary suspended. These e-visa are not valid. There is notice on the visa website (https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/). So please cross check with the authorities before your travel.

Comment: @Dexter according to the notice, the block is valid for Chinese citizens and people who live in China, and I am neither.

Comment: I guess, happy journey then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you'll be fine.** As the mail says, you have permission to *arrive* in India (the ETA) until March 6th, and will be granted a visa for the full 30 days on arrival to India.